# Couldn't detect an AMPS plugin to dispatch to

Tags: maven, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am currently in the process of creating a JIRA plugin.
After upgrading AMPS from 6.3.15 to 8.0.0 and running `atlas-debug` / `atlas-run` I am greeted with the following maven error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:amps-dispatcher-maven-plugin:8.0.0:debug (default-cli) on project soc-sync: **Couldn't detect an AMPS plugin to dispatch to** -> [Help 1]

What do I have to do to be able to run my JIRA plugin again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the introduction of AMPS 8.0.0 the maven plugins for the atlassian tools were renamed: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/ATLASSDK-147

What was previously `maven-jira-plugin` is now `jira-maven-plugin`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId> <!-- change here, was maven-jira-plugin -->
            <version>8.0.0</version> <!-- upgrade this or the amps.version property to 8.0.0 -->
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    <plugins>
    ...
<build>
```

The general rule seems to be: what was `maven-XYZ-plugin` is now `XYZ-maven-plugin`